# How to use the Angular services in a Worker?

Tags: angular, multithreading, worker

I have a web [worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) created in which I want to use the current functions that are placed in an [Angular Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). Tried passing them through the postMessage but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is that what you're asking can't be done. You cannot inject an Angular service into a worker. For background data, PWA actions, caching, calculations, and all that is doable, but not service injection. Think of a worker as a script built into the browser that wraps around your DOM, and Angular as a wrapper for javascript code that runs in the DOM. It's just not in Angular's scope to do that. At least, that's my take on the matter.

Comment: why not introduce just fully independent angular dependency injection and combine it with async communication?

Answer (score 0):

There was some independent tries to use Angular in web workers around Angular 7. Currently Angular support for web workers is officially deprecated - this is based on a discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2305

What still could make sense depending on a use-case is to use dependency injection to keep the codebase consistent and use rxjs wrapped communication between angular app and the worker. There are also other ongoing discussions around Angular and webworkers and integrations of external libraries - eg in https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/15059 thread one idea is to isolate the logic used by a worker and the worker as a provider:

```
{
      provide: FIBONACCI_WEBWORKER_FACTORY,
      useValue: function (): Worker {
        return new Worker('projects/fibonacci-webworker/src/lib/fibonacci', {
          name: 'fibonacci.worker',
          type: 'module',
        });
      },
    }
```

Definitely there are use-cases, needs and ideas and it's worth to follow to find possible workarounds depending on the case and eventually expecting official solution/support.

[small update]
if this is purely about the logic and services and you'd like to have similar developer experience of dependency injection (eg no components) you could consider in the `main.ts`:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(WorkerModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

and then the `worker-module.ts` to be sth like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { WebWorkerCoreService } from './webworker-core.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    WebWorkerCoreService,
    SomeOtherCommonService,
    SomeWebworkerToMainAppCommunicationService
  ],
  // bootstrap: [],
})
export class ExtensionModule {
  constructor(private webWorkerCoreService: WebWorkerCoreService) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(app: any) {
    // this method is required when there is no bootstrap in @NgModule
    // this is just one place when you initiate any webworker tasks 
    this.webWorkerCoreService.init();
  }
}
```